# Easy data conversion tool

Tags: ssis

I often have data in Excel or text that I need to get into SqlServer. I can use ODBC to query the Excel file and I can parse the text file.  What I want though is some tool that will just grab the data and put it into tables with little / no effort.  Does anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the **SQL Server Import/Export Wizard** ?

In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click your Database Name, and select **Tasks** menu, **Import Data**.  For Data Source, select **Microsoft Excel**, browse to the **.XLS**...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sql Server look at [Integration Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/technologies/integration/default.mspx) (SSIS).

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [parse-o-matic](http://www.parse-o-matic.com/)

Comment: Kewl, didn't even know this existed. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it'd be pretty easy to write a script that reads the text file, and converts it to "INSERT * into TABLE" Sql statements. I suspect this has already been done, but a simple implementation would be less than 100 lines of code in your favorite scripting language.

Hey, Google says SQLServer comes with such a tool, [BULK INSERT](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-load-text-or-csv-file-data-into-sql-server.html):

Answer (score 0):

Use DTS or SSIS depending on which version of SQL Server you have. There is an import wizard which can get you started, but data imports are rarely simple and usually involve some sort of data cleanup so that your incoming data is acceptable to the table where you intend to store it. Excel data, in my experience, is usually particularly bad inthis respect becasue it often isn't stored properly in Excel to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen commercial tools that do this. I create this kind of tools at work all the time, and the data validation is not trivial. This just makes sure that you don't have bad data making it into your database.

I found that for simple data conversion needs something like [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.com/) is pretty good. It still needs programming though. This framework is fairly easy to use, and somebody with a little bit of experience could bang something out for you.

On further thought, you can use the SQL Server [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to upload the contents of a text file. This is a command-line utility and has a lot of switches. I would suggest you experiment on a test table before you use this in a production table.

It's been a while since I used it, so I can't remember if you can directly use an Excel spreadsheet. Text files are always the easiest to deal with in any case.